# Multiple nodes in a single Views row

Tags: 8, views

I have a content type **Cars** and a content type **WheelManufacturer**.
Of course a **WheelManufactorer** node is referenced by a **Car** node.

I'm trying to create a View (in D8) that will fetch some fields from the **Car** nodes and some fields from the corresponding **WheelManufacturer** node.

I'm trying to do that by using **relationships** in Views... but I have a problem: I can add relationships to, ie Term Reference or Image fields, but not to Entity Reference ones... those fields just don't appear in the list.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3637164) - looks like it can be relevant.

Comment: thanks for your input.. anyway i've changed approach (and edited the OP), because what i wanted to do didn't look very sane :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've understood, it is actually NOT possible in Drupal 8: https://drupal.org/node/1906806

**EDIT**: the patch at the above link DOES work for me with the interdiff I just posted, so if you feel adventurous, you can give it a try!